# Ransack search for integer and string values from single search field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ransack

I am using Rails 4 with Ransack.

I cant make to work searching for integer and string values.

So far I tried this code.

In view:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name_cont, "Nepieciešama meklēšāna pēc ID, vārda un telefona nr" %>         
    <%= f.text_field :name_or_phone_number_cont_or_id_eq, :placeholder => 'Meklēt pēc ID,vārda vai tel.nr.' %>
  </div>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
<% end %>
```

In controller :

```
 def index

    @search = Advertisement.search(params[:q])
    @advertisements = @search.result

   respond_with(@advertisements)
  end
```

This gives me error:

> undefined method `name_or_phone_number_cont_or_id_eq' for

Is there any workaround to this problem?
Or I need to convert id to string for search purposes ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to use `f.search_field` instead `f.text_field`. Can you try it?

Comment: @Doguita Still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the code to your model, for you to be able to search for string and integer.

```
ransacker :id do
    Arel.sql("to_char(\"#{table_name}\".\"folio\", '99999999')")
  end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).