# How Ransack search field with multiple different predicates work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I m creating a filter which searches the three query as using Ransack predicates such as _matches_all and _cont and _eq.

the same question address not found the answer  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148185/ransack-search-for-integer-and-string-values-from-single-search-field)

I have tried the solution below but this doesn't work.

```
<%= f.label :category_name_matches_all_or_schedules_county_eq, "search" %>
<%= f.search_field :category_name_matches_all_or_schedules_county_eq %>
```

Comment: What error your facing?

Comment: Are `category_name` and `schedules_county` the attributes of model that you search? I think you should post whole search form, and schema of your model. It will be easier to resolve.